# How can I run a series of sql scripts with EF 4.3 Migrations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to do something like this in the `Seed` method:

```
foreach (string sqlFile in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"SqlScripts")))
            {
                string sqlText = File.OpenText(sqlFile).ReadToEnd();
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlText);
            }
```

When I run Update-Database I get the error:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\SqlScripts'.
```

So clearly update database is running from the VS bin directory and not from the project directory. Without having to resort to hard coding a path to the project (there are multiple developers working on this), how do I go about getting the path of the assembly that contains the `DbContext`?

Comment: Why don't you provide an absolute path then?

Comment: @MikeBantegui Because not all of the devs work off the same base path. (Which annoys me, but I have no control over it.) Plus it seems inelegant.

Comment: You can map to the absolute path of the currently executing assembly. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx

Comment: @MikeBantegui Yeah I tried Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) and the assembly is not being run from the bin directory it is in 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\9D00W24T.P01\L97G1HNR.00Q\7c0bcc72\bc512abc_5a10cd01\'

Comment: Another possible solution would be to add the SQL files as resources and just do
 context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Resources.XXX.sql);

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do something similar, but I always found Seed a little dim given that the point of Migrations is a versioned database, while a Seed command ignores versioning - so it can easily shoot you in the foot. The preferable result is data motion in Migrations instead. So, here we go:

([Full source on GitHub, with a few other Migrations commands](https://gist.github.com/b9chris/de66f90ea688a5fc1e5f).)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public abstract class ExpandedDbMigration
    : System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration
{
    public void SqlFile(string path)
    {
        var cleanAppDir = new Regex(@"\\bin.+");
        var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        dir = cleanAppDir.Replace(dir, "") + @"\";
        var sql = File.ReadAllLines(dir + path);

        string[] ignore = new string[]
        {
            "GO",   // Migrations doesn't support GO
            "/*",   // Migrations might not support comments
            "print" // Migrations might not support print
        };

        foreach (var line in sql)
        {
            if (ignore.Any(ig => line.StartsWith(ig)))
                continue;   

            Sql(line);
        }
    }
}
```

`AppDomain`... gets you the proper directory for your Models Project, instead of pointing you to Visual Studio as other methods would.

The Regex cleans up what's returned in case it's running from a bin folder.

ReadAllLines reads in your Sql script; in this case it's stored in \Sql\blah.sql but you could put it somewhere else.

The foreach/ignore prevents commands like "GO" from getting in, which will error out when used in Migrations, and are frequently emitted from tools like Sql Server Management Studio Generate Scripts.

Finally the foreach dumps each line out to Migrations.

Usage:

```
using Brass9.Data.Entity.Migrations;

public partial class FillZips : ExpandedDbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        SqlFile(@"Migrations\Sql\2013-08-15 FillTable.sql");
    }
```

Notice the change in inheritance, from DbMigration to ExpandedDbMigration.

Replace the argument to SqlFile with whatever the path is to the sql file inside your Migrations-enabled project.